# Converting input values to date and varchar2

Tags: oracle, plsql

1. How can I convert an input value to `DATE`?
2. How can I convert an input character to `VARCHAR2`?

I'm getting an error:

> ORA-06550: line 8, column 60:
>   PLS-00201: identifier 'N' must be declared
>   ORA-06550: line 8, column 19:
>   PL/SQL: Item ignored
>   06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
>   *Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.

My code is:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;  --for Oracle SQL Developer working
DECLARE
  --declaring variables for input datas
  vegzams_number    EXAM.egzams_number%TYPE     := &input_number_of_egzam;
  vid_student       EXAM.ID_STUDENT%TYPE        := &input_id_student;
  vid_subject       EXAM.id_subject%TYPE        := &input_id_subject;
  vid_teacher       EXAM.id_teacher%TYPE        := &input_id_teacher;
  vid_place_of_exam EXAM.id_place_of_exam%TYPE  := &input_id_place_of_exam;

  --PROBLEM HERE WITH THIS TWO VARIABLES
  vexams_date       EXAM.exams_date%TYPE        := TO_DATE(&input_date_of_egzam);
  vgot_a_mark       EXAM.got_a_mark%TYPE        := TO_CHAR(&input_good_mark_T_of_bad_N);

  --end declaring variables for input datas

  Command_text VARCHAR2(200); --for INSERT INTO EXAM command

  exams_rec EXAM%rowtype;     --declaring table

  --cursor declaration
  CURSOR c_exams IS SELECT egzams_number, ID_STUDENT, id_subject,
  id_teacher, exams_date, id_place_of_exam, got_a_mark FROM EXAM;

  --procedure declaration 
  PROCEDURE Insert_row(pegzams_number IN number,
  pId_student IN number,
  pid_subject IN number,
  pid_teacher IN number,
  pexams_date IN DATE,
  Pid_place_of_exam IN number,
  Pgood IN varchar2)IS
  BEGIN               
    Command_text := 'INSERT INTO EXAM VALUES (:v1, :v2, :v3, :v4, :v5, :v6, :v7)';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE Command_text USING pegzams_number, pId_student, pid_subject,
    pid_teacher, pexams_date, Pid_place_of_exam, Pgood;
    COMMIT;
  END;
  --procedure end

BEGIN --main begin
  OPEN c_exams;
  FETCH c_exams INTO exams_rec;
    Dbms_output.put_line('Date: ' ||exams_rec.exams_date);
  CLOSE c_exams;
END;
```

Comment: try use to_date base on your input format or if you have a specific calendar supply it in function call. to_date('10/25/1375','MM/DD/YYYY','NLS_CALENDAR=PERSIAN')

Comment: what is EXAM.got_a_mark%TYPE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using substitution variables, you need to enclose string values (but not numbers) in quotes:

```
  vexams_date       EXAM.exams_date%TYPE        := TO_DATE('&input_date_of_egzam');
```

Without quoting whatever value you supply is interpreted as an identifier, and there is no table/column/local variable with that name. For some date formats you'd see calculation errors too as they can sort of look like numeric expressions (03/11/2014, for example, is 0.000135..., which isn't a valid argument for `to_date` either, or 03/Nov).

If you turn `set verify on` you can see the before-and-after values it's trying to interpret; from the error you appear to have supplied `'N'` as the date value, which is going to fail anyway... presumably that was a mistake on data entry or definition.

You should also be specifying the format model you're expecting rather than relying on your current NLS_DATE_FORMAT.

If your next variable is supposed to be a string, you don't need `to_char`, just the quotes;

```
  vgot_a_mark       EXAM.got_a_mark%TYPE        := '&input_good_mark_T_of_bad_N';
```